# PHP query (including PostGiS functions) returns nothing

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I made a script to return IDs to me based on if a point is within a polygon. Currently this works when I invoke the script on my DB or on Postman, though when I invoke it else where it does not work.

I've looked into the post request body and 'Coordinates' is not a geography it is and encoded version (my guess), which I've tried to unpack within the query which hasn't worked. The only way I was able to unpack it within a different query was st_asgeojson and then use json_decode on the result but I want this to be done in one query.

Coordinates is passed as the following code:

```
"0101000020E6100000000000000040604000000000000039C0"
```

I want to convert this either outside the query or within it, to then get the results from my query. My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php

require_once('../db.php');

$rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$decoded = json_decode($rawdata, true);
$coordVar = handleCoords($decoded['event']['data']['new']['Coordinates']['coordinates']);

$res = pg_query_params($conn, 'SELECT "ShapeID" FROM "Shapes" WHERE st_within( ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326), "Coordinates"::geometry) ', array($coordVar[0], $coordVar[1]));
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    print_r($row['ShapeID]);
}
   

function handleCoords($data) {
    return array($data[0], $data[1]);
}

?>
```

Comment: it is a `bytea`, the underlying storage type for geometries/geography. `select st_asText('0101000020E6100000000000000040604000000000000039C0');` -->  `POINT(130 -25)`.  Not too sure where you are seeing this though (you use "coordinates" at 3 different places in your code). Make sure the lat-long you feed to st_makePoint are valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing my queries I obtained "Coordinates" from one of my tables which was a bytea code when looking at the results, as this is a geography data type. I got around this by using the ::geometry conversion, thinking about this, the issue I had was a simple fix. As the coordinates passed through the POST request body was also of the same data type, geography, therefore applying the same conversion would allow the query to work when invoked from any application.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

require_once('../db.php');

$rawdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$decoded = json_decode($rawdata, true);
$coordVar = handleCoords($decoded['event']['data']['new']['Coordinates']);

$res = pg_query_params($conn, 'SELECT "ShapeID" FROM "Shapes" WHERE st_within( ST_SetSRID( $1::geometry, 4326), "Coordinates"::geometry) ', array($coordVar));
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    print_r($row['ShapeID]);
}
   
?>
```